# How can'I test angularJs event '$on'?

Tags: angularjs, events, karma-jasmine

I'am using angularJs and I want to test $on event in my controller so I try to write test case in this way :

```
 beforeEach(inject(function ($controller,$injector) {
        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
         controller = $controller('MyController', { 
            $scope: $scope
         }); 
     }));
     spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast').and.callThrough();
     spyOn($rootScope, '$on').and.callThrough();

      it('should set $rootScope.settings.layout.pageBodySolid to false', function() {
            controller = CreateTarget();
        expect($rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect($rootScope.settings.layout.pageBodySolid).toBe(false);
        });
```

But I get this error :

> Error: spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for $broadcast()

I also try to do  test in this way :

```
 beforeEach(inject(function ( $controller,$injector) {
        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
         controller = $controller('MyController', { 
            $scope: $scope
         });
          CreateTarget = function() {
                $controller('MyController', {$scope: $scope});
            }

     }));

 it('should set $rootScope.settings.layout.pageBodySolid to false', function() {
            controller = CreateTarget();
            $rootScope.$broadcast('$viewContent');
            expect($rootScope.settings.layout.pageBodySolid).toBe(false);
        });
```

This time I get this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'layout' of undefined

And this is my controller event

```
$scope.$on('$viewContent', function () {

                    $rootScope.settings.layout.pageBodySolid = false;
                    $rootScope.settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed = false;
                });
```

I don't know how can I do this. It's really my first experience with angularJs test I need your help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues here:

First, the `spyOn`.  The `$scope` you pass into your controller is actually a new instance, yet you're spying on the `$rootScope` object, so they're two totally different instances.

Second, you don't necessarily want to test that `$broadcast` or `$on` are called because then you are essentially testing Angular.  What you want to test in those cases is your own code and the outcome of the event broadcast.

So, in your case, what you want to test is that 'when the $viewContent event is received, those two properties on `$rootScope` should be set to false.

Which brings me to my third point:  the `layout undefined` message is because you're trying to set a value on the `settings` property of `$rootScope`, but you never initialize that to anything.  At the point you're setting it, it is undefined.

TL;DR, this is how you could test this (note:  this code may need tweaked.  I'm typing this by memory and not actually testing that it works.  This is just to give you the idea)

```
 beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $injector, _$rootScope_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        $rootScope.settings = {
             layout : {
                 pageBodySolid : true,
                 pageSidebarClosed : true
             }
        };

        controller = $controller('MyController', { 
            $scope: $scope
        });        
     }));

 it('should set $rootScope.settings.layout properties to false', function() {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('$viewContent');

            // Run a digest to notify watchers
            $rootScope.$digest();

            expect($rootScope.settings.layout.pageBodySolid).toBe(false);
            expect($rootScope.settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed).toBe(false);
        });
```

Comment: Thank you very much @sma for your answer and all this informations. I will  follow your code to do my test.

Comment: The properties **pageBodySolid** and **pageSidebarClosed**  @sma should been set to true on the `inject function` ?because when running the test I get this error : `Expected true to be false.`

Comment: Are you running the $rootScope.$digest()?

Comment: It's Ok now  it was because of a grammar mistake I didn't pay attention on it . Thank you very much you have saved my day.

Comment: Cool.  Glad that helped.